# How to change repository in the existing xcode bot?

Tags: xcode-bots

I need to migrate my Xcode Bot to another repository and I wish to keep build history. In the edit bot interface (both browser and Xcode) repository field is not editable. How can I migrate?

OS X Server version 3.1.2

Comment: Check out my [article](http://honzadvorsky.com/blog/2015/5/4/under-the-hood-of-xcode-server) and look at how you can edit the CouchDB underlying data of Xcode Server. There you should be able to edit your Bot's Blueprint to use a different URL.

Comment: @czechboy your article is great! Unfortunately, when I've migrated that machine to Yosemite and OS X Server 4, I did a clean install so question is a bit outdated.

Comment: Oh ok, but I guess if you wanted to do the same even on the new Xcode Server (change the origin URL without losing the Bot's history), I'd recommend this for both the old and new version :)

Comment: Hey @czechboy, I've tried your proposal, edited Bot Blueprint values and saved the document. However, it did not change the repository used by the bot. When I integrate the bot after changing the DB, it agains checks out from the old repo. I think this information is stored or cached in somewhere else. Do you have any other proposals?

Comment: Yeah it's cached in Redis - you need to either restart your machine or restart your Xcode Server with `sudo xcrun xcscontrol --restart`

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but i suspect people will find this and look for an answer as it is the top result in google. This is how you do it:

1. change the repo you point to in git
2. open your Xcode project, select the bot and hit edit bot
3. in the repositories tab, uncheck the one that you want to update
4. hit done
5. go back to edit bot
6. you should now see the new repo instead of the old one